# Searching for something in Database (2) - SELECT - Need to search in 2 tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

[image]
As you can see in the print screen above, I am wondering, if it is possible to check if there is one thing in two tables at once WITH gaining whole one row if found (logical 1). Without making 2 queries. I need to look, if "fajne-to-jest" is in table1 or table2, and then take data row. I'm doing it in 2 queries... but question is, is it possible to check this information using one query? Mabye something else? Most efficent way? The best way?

@Gordon Linoff gave me this:

```
select (exists (select 1 from table1 where url = 'fajne-to-jest')) as in_table1,
       (exists (select 1 from table2 where url = 'fajne-to-jest')) as in_table2;
```

But this produces: [image]

And I want query to produce this + data from this row, like this:
[image]

Comment: Which `id` is to be returned when found in both?

Comment: What if this row exists in both tables?

Comment: this exact 'url' won't exist in both tables. @spiil

Comment: @Stavr00 id of this exact row, that contain url we search for

Comment: is `url` unique?

Comment: Yes, url is unique @AC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick stab at this, haven't tested it at all:

```
select 
    IF(table1.id IS NULL, 0, 1) as table1,
    IF(table2.id IS NULL, 0, 1) as table2,
    COALESCE(table1.id, table2.id, "NONE") as id,
    `master`.url
from
(select 'fajne-to-jest' as url)  `master`
left join table1 on table1.url = `master`.url
left join table2 on table2.url = `master`.url
;
```

*Should* always give a single row, whether it's found in 0,1, or both tables.  You said url is unique so shouldn't need to worry about repeats, but if IDs don't match then this favors table1 (and prints "NONE" if not in either table).

Comment: Could you explain this query in detial?

Comment: What a `master` is ?

Comment: `master` is a temporary table created by the `select` inside parenthesis.

Comment: Yup, as @Stavr00 said it's an alias. As for the rest of it, the `left join`s mean that the result from master will be included in the results whether or not there is a match in table1 or 2. If they had instead been inner joins then there would be no result row if the url was missing from table1 or 2. The left joins make result columns null if there's no match, so if `table.id` is null then url is not in that table, else `id` is the actual id (that's all assuming `id` is declared `NOT NULL`). The if statements convert null/id to 0/1. `COALESCE` just returns the first non-null of its arguments.

Comment: Note that this only returns a single row if `url` is unique for both table1 & table2 -- if it's not unique then the query will return a bunch of rows.  In this case it would give all combinations of all the `id`s from both tables that have `url` equal to the search term (`master`) -- basically a cross join on url.